# Expo assembleRelease Android Cannot Find Symbol ReactNativeFlipper

Tags: java, android, react-native, gradle, expo

Im trying to build my react native app for android. Im following the guide on React-Native's website, but when I use ./gradlew assembleRelease in the android folder I get the following error:

```
MainApplication.java:71: error: cannot find symbol
    ReactNativeFlipper.initializeFlipper(this, getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager());
```

Ive tried updating ReactNativeFlipper, reinstalling node modules, ./gradlew clean, and ensuring the package names are all the same. If you need any other files please let me know and ill update this post.

It might be worth noting that my project does not have a release folder. Not sure why or if that affects anything.

Answer (score 0):

Remove/comment out `release` folder in `.gitignore`.